# “user Does not exists” Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I started this tutorial (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-native-firebase-tutorial/) on Firebase and React Native. Everything is working well overall.

But I have this error: “`User does not exist anymore.`” for the Login.
However, users are well rooted in Firebase.

```
const onLoginPress = () => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            const uid = response.user.uid
            const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
            usersRef
                .doc(uid)
                .get()
                .then(firestoreDocument => {
                    if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                        alert("User does not exist anymore.")
                        return;
                    }
                    const user = firestoreDocument.data()
                    navigation.navigate('Home', {user})
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(error)
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
        })

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have created the user document in the `users` collection? This is done in the `onRegisterPress()` function in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just checked. I wrote the function well `onRegisterPress()`

Comment: Do you see the user doc in the database, via the Firebase console?

Comment: That's it ? there is a registered user

| Identifiant       | Suppliers | Date create | Last Connexion | UID user |
|-------------------|-----------|-------------|----------------|----------|
| xxxxx@hotmail.com |           | 09/07/2021  | 10/07/2021     | xxxxxx   |
|                   |           |             |                |          |
|                   |           |             |                |          |

Comment: I think this is the record in the Authentication service. But you should look in the Firestore service ("Firstore Database" vertical menu item): you should find a `users` collection there.

Comment: Indeed, there were no users in Firestore Database.
I copy / paste all the settings from my Firebase project into src / firebase / config.js and now it works (the tutorial was not very clear on this issue of settings). Thank you very much for these exchanges, it helped me to further my research.

Comment: Ok, glad to know that you solved your problem! I'll write an answer along those lines, thanks in advance to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
   const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
   usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then(firestoreDocument => {
            if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                alert("User does not exist anymore.")
                return;
             }
             const user = firestoreDocument.data()
             navigation.navigate('Home', {user})
        })
```

you actually query the `user` document with the id corresponding to the user's `uid` in the `users` collection.

This document is normally created by the `onRegisterPress()` function in the tutorial. If you get the "User does not exist anymore." message, it means that the user document is not present in the collection.

So you need to check why this is the case: the `onRegisterPress()` function was not called? The doc was deleted? There are security rules that prevent creating the document? etc...